# how to get email label from email id with gmail API?

Tags: google-api, imap, gmail-api

i have a problem how to get label email (promotions, updates, forums etc) with Gmail API with low cost computational.

my app used IMAP-idle for getting a new email.
a was search and get that IMAP not support label (promotions, update etc)

the other way is using Gmail API
i know i can get a list of email id by label
but that too much computational
'new id from IMAP -> search that id in every list of label (4 label)->get the label'
it's that possible to get the label of the message with one call?
thanks

Comment: Label != Category.  Labels are the tags users can use.  Categories are the different sub boxes of the Inbox.

Answer (score 0):

In the gmail web app you can search for lables  [label:friends](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) in the Gmail api you can also [search for messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q="label:friends"
```

the [message.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) method will then return all the messages within that label.   If you have the message id which i am not sure is the same from imap to the gmail api you then you can do a [message.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) which will return the label as well

Comment: I think the OP means categories.  I don't know if they're available through the API.

Comment: Ah, they are: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels : They are special labels with names like CATEGORY_PERSONAL